# Installed Android PWA and Google Play hybrid app version Conflict

Tags: android, google-play, progressive-web-apps

We developed both versions, cordova app and PWA Versions ( from the same code base).

Our conflict is that, if the users installs the PWA version ( which adds an app icon to the android homescreen) then if the user goes to the Play Store, and searchs for the "hybrid app" the app appears as "installed" when this is not true?

Is this because they share the same app code name?

In this case if the user wants to install the Google Play version then it has to unistall and then install again to be able to install the "Hybrid" non-PWA version...

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one app with the same package name eg "com.google.android.gmail" on any device at any time. So yes, if you want two different apps, then you need two different package names (also known as Application ids). This isn't just normal, it is true on all versions of android since the very beginning.

Comment: yes, but because my apps ( phonegap is generated from the same source code) then during build, it creates the browser version which is the PDW version, and then the phonegap one. They both share the same app name, The thing is because the PDW install a app like using the same app name, then that conflict arises.. thats what it looks like to me. But google play should be "smart to detected" that. Also because i dont want my user to be able to install the PWA and the hybrid one, thats why they have the same app code.

Comment: If you want an "instant" version from the web, which Play store will intelligently upgrade to the installed version you need to use Google Play Instant app: See here: https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant